# One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running. ISSUE NOT RESOLVING

Tags: magento2, cron, indexer

[image]

I'm getting this error on my dashboard and when i try to reindex through command line via this command from my magento root directory.

```
/var/www/html/magento
```

then

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

so it is giving me an error, see it below

> Could not open input file: bin/magento

[image]

Please help me, because many things are not working properly even my theme.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try [this topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron). To summarize, you must set up 3 cron jobs:

`*/1 * * * * <path-to-binary> -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run [>> <log-file>&]
*/1 * * * * <path-to-binary> -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/update/cron.php [>> <log-file>&]
*/1 * * * * <path-to-binary> -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run [>> <log-file>&]`

For example,

`*/1 * * * * /etc/php -c /etc/php.ini /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/cron.log&]
*/1 * * * * /etc/php -c /etc/php.ini /var/www/html/magento2/bin/update/cron.php [> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.log&]
*/1 * * * * /etc/php -c /etc/php.ini /var/www/html/magento2/bin/bin/magento setup:cron:run [> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup-cron.log&]`

You don't have to do anything to get cron to run; it runs on its own.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting this error on my dashboard and when i try to reindex
>   through command line via this command from my magento root directory.
>
> ```
> /var/www/html/magento
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> ```
>
> so it is giving me an error, see it below
>
> > Could not open input file: bin/magento

You were almost there. The first command should be

```
cd /var/www/html/magento
```

to change into the Magento directory

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need add `magento cron:run` to the cron. It's will run indexer process automatically.

Second, please look on command output that you run. You lost `cd` before 'magento root dir'

Comment: Your second answer sounds working but can you please tell me how can i add magento cron:run to the corn??

Comment: Do you try configure by official docs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html ?

Comment: I already did that all steps but in the "Configure cron groups for custom modules" is it important to setup? Another one thing i already add following lines in my crontab and saved it but do not know how to run it?